# How can I get the user's email returned to my asp.net web forms app from Facebook OAuth login?

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth, asp.net-membership, webforms

I have a web forms app (VS2012) that is using the template OpenAuth code to allow users to login via Facebook. It is a requirement of the ASP.Net Membership registration for my site  that an email address is provided, so I need to figure out a way of getting the user's email address in the returned authResult object.

I *thought* I had configured the Facebook app to provide the email (I added "email" to the  'User & Friend Permissions' field in the Permissions Settings page), but when I login to my website using Facebook, it does not indicate that an email address is required, and the resulting authResult only contains the basic user information (name, gender etc.)

It seems that to get the email address returned in the authResult, I need to somehow specify this in the call to Facebook, but the OpenAuth.RequestAuthentication() method doesn't appear to support this.

How can I get the user's email address back from the login request using the VS2012 template code?

Answer (score 0):

try to add an scope to your login url, for example:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=URI&scope=email

see **scope=email**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm aware that this can be done when logging in via a url, but my question refers to logging into Facebook using the OpenAuth template code that exists in Visual Studio 2012. With this there is no explicit url, just the call to the OpenAuth.RequestAuthentication() method (AFAIK).

Comment: ok, i had the same issue that you have now and a solved it with server side login via that url

Comment: So did you abandon the use of the OpenAuth template code completely? Or somehow integrate the server-side url login into it?